# USB C Port: Can I connect 2 dongles of wireless devices?

Tags: wireless-keyboard, wireless-headset, usb-3.1-type-c

I have a wireless keyboard and wireless headset both came with their USB-A dongles.
I have a Type-C port on my laptop and Type-C to Female A converter through which I am currently using my headset dongle and is working fine.
I am thinking about buying a Type-C hub, connecting both dongles to hub and then connecting the hub to Type-C port.

So is it possible then, to get both audio and keyboard working from same Type-C port?

Edit: This question is specific for the wireless devices.

Comment: Or you could just get a Type A hub.

Comment: Will they work on same port? Either type c or USB A?

Comment: Erm... you connect it to your current adapter...

Comment: Didn't get you what you want to say

Comment: "I have a [...] Type-C to Female A converter..."

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you **can buy** a Type-C hub and connect your peripherals there.

You will need adapters for your keyboard/mouse (Type-A to Type-C) as well **or** you buy a hub that already have Type-A connectors.

If your laptop have Type-A USB ports you can also buy a Type-A hub (most laptops already have 2 ports atleast).

USB hubs exists for this **exact** purpose: to connect multiple devices on a single port. You don't need to worry [because](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/three-things-you-should-know-about-usb-type-c/):

> USB 3.1 Type-C cables offer a transfer rate of 10Gbps, which is double the transfer speed of USB 3.0 (5 Gbps). Additionally, these cables will offer 20 volts and 5 amps of power.

Which means that you can plug anything and it will be powered properly.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @Aman Have we tried what? You have received two approaches to your problem.  An USB Type-C port is compatible with other connectors provided you use the appropriate adapter.  This is the correct answer to your question.

Comment: I meant this is theoretical. Have anyone tried the same, through any means, USB A or USB C??? I do not want to buy a costly Type-C hub later to found that only 1 device is able to work from it.

Comment: @Aman First, have you, atleast, read the answer from the thread you mention? He is talking about USB2. The hub he used wasn't powering the devices because USB2 only supplies 500mA and that wasn't enough for his devices. Type-C, or even USB 3.1 can supply more amperage to the devices connected (not sure how much but its a lot more). I'm assuring that a Type-C hub would supplie enough power to your keyboard / mouse.

Comment: I will add this to my answer as soon as possible, I'm on mobile right now

Comment: @Aman There isn’t any theoretical about this answer.  If you purchase a 2-port USB Type-C Hub, it means, you can connect two USB devices to that Type-C Hub.  Even the answer to your linked question agrees with this fact, even though that forum is an absolutely horrible place, to find accurate information.  Please be kind, if this answer does indeed answer your question, you should accept it.

Comment: I don't know much about drivers/firmware side but I do know that wireless headset is recognized through a port(USB A or C) also for wireless mouse. Reason for asking it here, to get the fact from the person, who "actually used" it, not based on theories(according to me this should work before even posting this question).

Comment: @Ramhound I think you missed my comment where I have written that " I do not want to buy a costly Type-C hub later to found that only 1 device is able to work from it." I will have no problem at all, accepting the answer, which will be relevant to my question. We all are here to solve problems/help each others, not to get upvotes/accepted answers/reputation(IMO at least). :-)

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira sorry for that confusing link. I think wireless dongles need less amount of power as compare to full device(headset or mouse) through wire. So dongles should be powered but maybe the hardware will use only 1 device to be recognized through a single port(headset working but mouse not working although both dongles are powered)

Comment: @Aman - You directed the comment to me.  I read it.  As I said before, this answer, isn't theoretical.  We should keep the commentary to a minimum.

Comment: @Ramhound please share some links, that will be great help, to read the practical feasibility of the same.